# How do I unsubscribe from an RSS feed in Opera?

Tags: rss, opera

I've got an RSS feed I've subscribed to in Opera, but do not wish to receive anymore.  Normally, to do this, I would either delete it, or simply uncheck it in the "Feeds -> Manage Feeds" dialog.  However, doing this not only unsubscribes me, but deletes **all** of the previously downloaded posts as well, and takes the category away on my feeds menu!  If I edit the feed to "never update", it only takes away automatic updates - if I manually refresh my feeds, it gets the new posts.

So, how can I *actually* unsubscribe, without losing every post previously downloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the feeds you don't want and set previously to never update into an "inactive" folder, and the feeds you want into an "active" folder. Then you can use manual refresh only on the "active" folder and not on all of your feeds.

This won't actually unsubscribe you from the feeds but it will keep your previously downloaded posts and you should only receive new posts when you actually want to.

Other way could be if you hack your way into the profile folder where Opera stores your mail and feeds (`C:\Documents and Settings\balazsm\Local Settings\Application Data\Opera\Opera\mail\store` on Windows XP), and manually archive the posts you need  (they are stored in text files) and then delete the feed from Opera. But I think nobody would want to do that actually because of the way Opera stores data. (accounts\years\months\days and posts in separate files inside, however there are different feeds in the same folders.)

Comment: Not perfect, but it definitely worked.  For anybody else that tries this, you have to specifically refresh that folder by right clicking on it.  The big manual refresh button on top will *still* get all of the feeds, even the inactive ones.